# Quick "non-shower" after morning bicycle commute

Tags: health, hygiene

I like to commute with my bicycle in the morning. It's just more relax than public transportation or motorcycling (or just whatever else, actually!).

But there's just one problem this summer.

Where I work, we don't have any access to showers. I probably don't need to tell you that sport + heat = sweat. And sweat can be, occasionally, smelly. That's something I will probably face soon.

I'm targeting for zero waste lifestyle, although still far from it. Do you know any magical mixture / cloth / trick I could use to get a quick wash after commuting? Something that can be reused and preferably made of natural components?

Comment: Related: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15594/; perhaps a duplicate: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/308/.

FWIW, I ride to work nearly every day (6.5 miles RT) and don't shower even though they are available with moderate inconvenience, so it can be done.

Answer (score 4):

You could take a small, fast-drying (outdoor) towel with you and wash your underarms (usually the most dominant source of smell) in the toilet.

Comment: You can of course do a whole body wash with just a small cloth and a basin (saves a lot of water over a shower).  But that relies on you being comfortable standing around naked in the gents at work...

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. With the type of company I'm in, I don't think it would be appropriate to stand (even in the toilets) with the upper body naked. I was looking for a solution I could apply in a very small room (i.e. one toilet room), where I have less than 1sq meter to move. Possibly still an applicable solution though...

Answer (score 2):

The cause of body odour are the chemical produced by bacteria that live on the skin in warm, moist areas like the armpits and on feet.

One way to reduce the amount of bacteria is to kill them off using vinegar. Vinegar is mild acid that certain bacteria can't survive in.

Get some cheap bulk clear vinegar and apply it with a wash cloth and then rinse the cloth afterwards.

Comment: Interesting answer! But wouldn't you get the same effect by washing yourself with a wash cloth and some (organic) soap?

Comment: Unless soap contains an anti bacterial agent it only lifts bacteria so it can be washed off with water.

Comment: what about lemon? I like its smell more than vinegar!